# font-weight inline use changing sans-serif font to serif in some Outlook for Windows

Tags: html-email

Newbie using a \div\ and inline font-weight around text in an HTML email to more closely match a light web sans-serif font. It renders fine using Email on Acid's tool. Code as follows:

\\div style="text-align: left; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; **font-weight: 300;** color: #333333; line-height: 28px;"\\

One PC/Outlook VIP stakeholder is seeing the Arial in a serif Times New Roman-ish font. I don't see how.

How can I overcome that -- without too much CSS? (I'm a CSS-novice.) Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional tags for Outllook to force font-family(only native) and line-height

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">
    td,
    td p,
    td a {            
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif !important;                 
    }

    td p,
    td a {
        mso-line-height-rule: exactly !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Also for reference, Microsoft/Outlook have announced this will be removed in future versions of Outlook.  
But because it's email should still include the fix above for older versions/

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't support Helvetica Neue. When you include a special web font in the font-family it will revert to Times New Roman.

See more about fonts for email here: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/best-font-for-email-everything-you-need-to-know-about-email-safe-fonts/

Comment: Thank you. Truly appreciate your patience.

Comment: Please include important elements from the page so its in Stack Overflow in case the page is lost or dead.

Comment: As usual, Outlook 2007/10/13 don’t play ball and don’t support font-face or <link>. Also, when you include a special web font in the font-family it will revert to Times New Roman, whether you have specified a fallback or not. When using the font-face method of importing fonts, ensure you wrap it in media{}:

<style>
     media {
     font-face {
  font-family: 'Timmana';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Timmana'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/timmana/v3/6xKvdShfL9yK-rvpOmzRKV4KQOI.woff2) format('woff2');
     }
    }
</style>